# Creating a Continuous Decision Variable between 0 and 1 in Python-MIP Interface

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python, coin-or

This task appears to be harder than it seems to me.

I want to create a continuous variable $x \in [0,1]$.

To test this, I did use the open-source [Python-MIP](https://www.python-mip.com/) interface which uses the [CBC-Solver](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc) out of the box.

I wrote a simple code example to see if the variable $x$ will get the float value of $0.4$ by doing the following: \begin{align}\max&\quad x\\\text{s.t.}&\quad x\in[0,1]\\&\quad a=2\\&\quad b=5\\&\quad x\le a/b\end{align}

```py
    from mip import Model, maximize, CONTINUOUS, CBC

    model = Model(solver_name=CBC)

    a = 2
    b = 5

    x = model.add_var('x',lb = 0, ub =1, var_type=CONTINUOUS)

    model += x <= a/b

    model.objective = maximize(x)

    model.optimize()

    if model.num_solutions:
            for v in model.vars:
               # if v.x > 0:
                    print('{v.name} = {v.x}'.format(**locals()))
                    print('          ', end='')
```

Instead, I am getting a value of $x=0.0$.

```
Using Python-MIP package version 1.6.6
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: Trunk
Build Date: Dec 26 2019 

Starting solution of the Linear programming problem using Primal Simplex

x = 0.0
          Coin0506I Presolve 0 (-1) rows, 0 (-1) columns and 0 (-1) elements
Clp0000I Optimal - objective value 0
Coin0511I After Postsolve, objective 0, infeasibilities - dual 0 (0), primal 0 (0)
Clp0032I Optimal objective 0 - 0 iterations time 0.012, Presolve 0.00, Idiot 0.00
```

Comment: What happens if instead of `x<= a/b` you actually write `x<=0.4`? Will it give you the same answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I also tested it with the Gurobi solver within this interface, getting the same result.

Comment: Did you try defining a=2.0?

Comment: Also which python version do you have? If you have Py2 you need to use a//b

Comment: @independentvariable I tried $a=2.0$ but got the same result. I used Python 3.7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know much about Python-mip but looking at the [code](https://github.com/coin-or/python-mip/blob/1.7.0/mip/model.py#L1286), `maximize` expects a `LinExpr`, so I tried:

```py
model.objective = maximize(1*x)
```

which gives the expected output.

Edit: I also opened a [PR](https://github.com/coin-or/python-mip/pull/59) to allow `maximize(var)` and `minimize(var)`.

Edit: The PR has been merged, this shouldn't be a problem in `>1.7.2`.